# Apache Spark | specific time frame aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, aggregation, apache-spark-sql

I'm in need of a way of aggregate a dataset by weekly. Here's my dataset

```
|      date|organization_id|media_package_id|event_uuid |
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
|2016-10-25|              1|              11|     76304d|
|2016-10-25|              1|              11|     e6285b|
|2016-10-22|              2|              21|     16c04d|
|2016-10-22|              2|              21|     17804d|
|2016-10-22|              2|              21|     18904x|
|2016-10-21|              2|              21|     51564q|
|2016-10-07|              4|              98|     12874t|
|2016-10-05|              4|              98|     11234d|
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Lets assume that a Spark job is running daily for getting the desired aggregation result. And I want results as in a week basis for example above data set after the aggregation would be.

```
|      date|organization_id|media_package_id|      count|
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
|2016-10-24|              1|              11|          2|
|2016-10-17|              2|              21|          4|
|2016-10-03|              4|              98|          2|
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Here if you see the date column it is taking the first day of the week (which I think is the best way)

I somehow managed to do the aggregation for daily basis. Here's how I did it

```
val data = MongoSupport.load(spark, "sampleCollection")
val dataForDates = data.filter(dataForDates("date").isin(dates : _*))

val countByDate = proofEventsForDates.groupBy("DATE", "ORGANIZATION_ID", "MEDIA_PACKAGE_ID")
  .agg(count("EVENT_UUID").as("COUNT"))

val finalResult = impressionsByDate
  .select(
    col("DATE").as("date"),
    col("ORGANIZATION_ID").as("organization_id"),
    col("MEDIA_PACKAGE_ID").as("media_package_id"),
    col("COUNT").as("count")
  )
```

Here, at the beginning to filter out the dataset, I'm passing a special `dates` list which consists of dates for at least about a month. And the result I'm getting is (which is not what I want)

```
|      date|organization_id|media_package_id|      count|
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
|2016-10-25|              1|              11|          2|
|2016-10-22|              2|              21|          3|
|2016-10-21|              2|              21|          1|
|2016-10-07|              2|              21|          1|
|2016-10-05|              2|              21|          1|
+----------+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

On here onwards I have no clue on getting this dataset aggregated weekly.

Comment: What happened to the row of `organization_id = 5`?

Comment: @mtoto Question edited. I was a little typo

Comment: based on your expected output in the same row `media_package_id` should be `21`, no?

Comment: @mtoto, yes you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `date` column is already of class `date`, you could use the functions `year()` and  `weekofyear()` to extract the missing grouping columns for the aggregation.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.weekofyear
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.year

(df
  .withColumn("week_nr", weekofyear($"date"))
  .withColumn("year", year($"date"))
  .groupBy("year",
           "week_nr",
           "organization_id",
           "media_package_id")
  .count().orderBy(desc("week_nr"))).show
+----+-------+---------------+----------------+-----+
|year|week_nr|organization_id|media_package_id|count|
+----+-------+---------------+----------------+-----+
|2016|     43|              1|              11|    2|
|2016|     42|              2|              21|    4|
|2016|     40|              4|              98|    2|
+----+-------+---------------+----------------+-----+
```

Comment: you should probably groupBy `year($"date")` as well as by `weekofyear` - otherwise if the data spans more than a year, you'll group the Nth week of different years together.